# How to add permalink to objects

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm not sure whether it is permalink that i want or something else, but here is what I need:

I have a template that displays objects like this:

```
{% for object in objects %}
{{object}}
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to identify an object from the same url.

Example:
If `www.domain.com/objects` displays all the objects then `www.domain.com/objects#1` should focus the browser window on the first object and `www.domain.com/objects#10` should focus the window on the tenth object.

I have seen this behavior in lot of sites including stack overflow and I wanted to know how to implement such behavior.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just HTML.

```
<ul>
{% for object in objects %}
  <li id="{{ object.id }}">{{ object }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: In HTML4 [id have to begin with a letter](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) and there are some older browser having problems with purely numerical ids, so it would be saver to do something like `<li id="object-{{ object.id }}">`. And then use addresses similar to `www.domain.com/objects#object-10`.

Comment: Thank you. If `www.domain.com/objects/#1` is the url, it is working nicely. But with pages in the url like `www.domain.com/objects/?page=2#10` it is not working properly. Any suggestions?